# strange behavior of to_h method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have condition var which need to be converted to hash but I always get an empty hash and I do not know why...The debug info is as follows.

```
0> p conditions
App 3069 stdout: {"email"=>"asdf.yuan@asdf.com"}
=> {"email"=>"asdf.yuan@asdf.com"}

0> p conditions.class
App 3069 stdout: ActionController::Parameters
=> ActionController::Parameters

0> p conditions.to_h
App 3069 stdout: {}
=> {}
```

And I tried to_hash, it just behaves as espected!!!really strange!!!

Comment: why you want  to transform into a hash, when it is already a hash? condition[:email] and you good to go? but to answer your question a dirty hack would be .to_a.to_h

Comment: the conditions = warden_conditions.dup. It is the suggested method of Devise about "How to allow user sign in using either email or username". I think the warden_conditions might have the possibility be not a hash. But who do you mean by .to_a.to_h? And why the to_h and to_hash would behave like this? I wanna get it understand, not just hack it. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing strange about it; `p conditions.to_h` is returning `{}` correctly as none of the keys are marked as permitted.

Take a look at the documentation for the method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h

> **to_h()**
>
> Returns a safe Hash representation of this parameter with all unpermitted keys removed.

Try setting a key as permitted as follows:

```
> permitted_conditions = conditions.permit(:email)
> permitted_conditions.to_h
=> {"email"=>"asdf.yuan@asdf.com"}
```

[`to_unsafe_h`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_unsafe_h) has the behavior you were originally looking for.

Comment: Tried, find to_unsafe_h do not work, only to_hash work... some object cannot find the method, I think it is rails implementation rather than Ruby core implementation. So when it is not Rails params, it cannot find the to_unsafe_h method.